# MapActionToProps is not Updating the Store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to update my Store, but it is not updating automatically.

Doesn't calling `MapActionToProps` updates the store without using the dispatch function.

Please Help. What is it, that I am doing wrong here.

This is My `App.js` File:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

    import logo from './logo.svg';
    import './App.css';
    import  { connect} from 'react-redux';
    import { updateUser } from './actions/users-actions';

    class App extends Component {
      constructor(props){
          super(props);
          this.onUpdateUser = this.onUpdateUser.bind(this);
      }
      onUpdateUser(){
          this.props.onUpdateUser('Sammy');
      }
      render() {
        console.log(this.props);
        return (

          <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
              <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
              <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
            </header>
            <p className="App-intro">
              To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
            </p>
            <button onClick={this.onUpdateUser}> Update User</button>
            {this.props.user} 
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    const mapStateToProps = state => ({
        products : state.products,
        user : state.user,
    })

    const mapActionsToProps =  {
               onUpdateUser : updateUser
    };  

    export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapActionsToProps)(App);
```

This is my `Action File`:

```
export const UPDATE_USER = 'users:updateUser';
export function updateUser(newUser){
        return{
               type:UPDATE_USER,
               payload:{
                    user:newUser
               }
        }
}
```

this is my `Reducer File`:

```
import { UPDATE_USER } from '../actions/users-actions';
export default function usersReducer(state='',type,payload){

    switch(type){
            case 'UPDATE_USER':
                return payload.user;
            default:
            return state

    }

}
```

Do I Need to call `store.dispatch()` Method?

Comment: Is there an error that you're getting?

Comment: no Error. i am getting a console log - webpackHotDevClient.js:138 ./src/reducers/user-reducer.js
  Line 1:  'UPDATE_USER' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars . Is this the reason??

Comment: The switch type case in your reducer isn't matching what your type in action. One is 'users:updateUser' and other is 'UPDATE_USER'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type in the reducer isn't matching what the action creator is dispatching. Your action has type:'users:updateUser' whereas the reducer is handling case 'UPDATE_USER'.

You can dispatch 'UPDATE_USER' as your type in the action creator and it should work.

Comment: Not Working . export const UPDATE_USER = 'UPDATE_USER';

export function updateUser(newUser){

        return{
               type:UPDATE_USER,
               payload:{

                    user:newUser

               }



        }


} i tried this. Still not working

Comment: Make sure that your reducer is called. Check the data in the redux extension or print a statement in that switch case.

Comment: yes thats the problem , the reducer is not getting called.   switch(type){
            case 'updateUser':
            console.log('reducer is called');
                return payload.user;
            default:
            return state

    } i tried to log . it is not showing

Answer (score 2):

You really cannot do what you want without calling the `dispatch` function in your Component. In you case, as you are trying to get the `state` and make the `dispatch` from the Redux on the Component in the same time - you need to call the `dispatch` directly from `mapActionsToProps` in the next way:

```
const mapActionsToProps = dispatch => ({
    onUpdateUser: (yourData) => dispatch(updateUser(yourData));
});
```

This is will work for you.

And also you need to update your `Action`:

```
export const UPDATE_USER = 'users:updateUser';
export function updateUser(newUser) {
   return {
     type: UPDATE_USER,
     newUser
   }
}
```

And `Reducer` also too:

```
import { UPDATE_USER } from '../actions/users-actions';
export default function usersReducer(state = '', action){

    switch(action.type){
       case 'UPDATE_USER':
          return action.newUser;
       default:
          return state
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried this. but getting error. TypeError: this.props.onUpdateUser is not a function
App.onUpdateUser
src/App.js:16
  13 | }
  14 | onUpdateUser(){
  15 | 
> 16 |     this.props.onUpdateUser('Sammy');
  17 | 
  18 | }
  19 | render() {

Comment: @codemt I update mapActionToProps func. Reuse it now please

Comment: i solved the issue man. by changing users:updateUsers to UPDATE_USER. but now i cant print the new state.

Comment: i tried your method. but i get Error - i am confused with the object "yourData" is it something i get from my actions?

Comment: @codemt Yes, this is what you will put in the `this.props.onUpdateUser('Sammy');` in you case - 'Sammy' string

Comment: Also I did not found in you question a string with that you say above - `users:updateUsers`... About getting the state from Redux - you need to open a new question and put more code @codemt

Answer (score 0):

Have you provided proper reducer path to your store?

```
const store = createStore(
        reducer,
        composeWithDevTools(
            applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)
        )
    );
```

Here, you should be importing 'reducer' by specifying proper path of your reducer file.

Also, you might have missed to wrap your app React UI container inside react-redux library's provider.

```
ReactDOM.render(  
  <Provider store={ store }>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it using `UPDATE_USER` in action file ,

where it was 'user:updateuser'